# Getting PInvokeStackImbalance when using webdriver 2.5.1

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Im getting a PInvokeStackImbalance error when running debug in VS2010 using selenium webdriver 2.5.1 dlls.

If i do exactly the same but switch the dlls to the old 2.4 version there's no problems

Am i missing something??

**Error message:**
PInvokeStackImbalance was detected
Message: A call to PInvoke function 'WebDriver!OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriverServer+StartServerFunction::Invoke' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

**Calling code:**

```
_driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Thx for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2356). It's already been fixed in the trunk of the project. If you are able to build from source, you can pick up the fix now. If you are unable to do so, the fix should be available in the next binary release.

Comment: Thanks for the response, glad to hear it wasn't me who couldn't figure out vs2010 ;)